# How to calculate litecoin pool difficulty from cgminer diff value?

Tags: litecoin, difficulty

How could I get litecoin pool share difficulty from the diff value reported by cgminer?
For example when cgminer reports diff 16 pool diff is 2^-20. But i am interested how to calculate it?